# How to concatenate or create a variable in gitlab-ci.yml job template script section?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a test script that is always the same "banana" but I need to append something else in different jobs, such as "orange", "lime", "strawberry"

```
.job_template:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script: banana

job1:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - banana orange

job2:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - banana lime

job3:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - banana strawberry
```

How can I achieve this?
The "banana" part is pretty long, it looks like:

```
- docker run castsofwaredocker/gitlab:cypressrunner_master https://${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.helloworld.io --record --key "xxxx" --parallel --group "prod" --ci-build-id $CI_PIPELINE_ID "--spec cypress/integration/store/26-login/*.js"
```

So I'm basically only replacing this part "cypress/integration/store/26-login/*.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in [GitLab CI/CD docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#gitlab-ciyml-defined-variables).

> You are able to use other variables inside your variable definition (or escape them with `$$`):

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` can be simplified in this way:

```
variables:
  BANANA_CMD: 'docker run castsofwaredocker/gitlab:cypressrunner_master https://${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}.helloworld.io --record --key "xxxx" --parallel --group "prod" --ci-build-id $CI_PIPELINE_ID'

.job_template:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script: eval '$BANANA_CMD "--spec cypress/integration/store/26-login/*.js"'

job1:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - eval '$BANANA_CMD orange'

job2:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - eval '$BANANA_CMD lime'

job3:
  extends: .job_template
  script:
    - eval '$BANANA_CMD strawberry'
```

Comment: It works @AmirMohammad Dadkhah! Thank you. Question. If I wanted to clean up even more, like parts of "BANANA_CMD" into more pieces, like separating the --key "xxxx" or --group "prod", do you still recommend using eval?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: You can split `BANANA_CMD` and can define `--key "xxxx"` & `--group "prod"` as variables (job level or global level) too, and use them like `eval '$BANANA_CMD $KEY_FLAG $GROUP_FLAG ...'`